# gpflow model.elbo throws KeyError and NotImplementedError

Tags: python, gpflow

Im trying to train an SVGP model in gpflow with X_train having shape (140,1433) and y_train having shape (140,). I get a KeyError from dispatcher.py but the error message doesnt specify which part of my code called that file, and I cant figure out what the rest of the error message means either. I copy full relevant code and full error message:

```
import numpy as np
import gpflow
import tensorflow as tf
from gpflow.mean_functions import Constant
from gpflow.models import SVGP
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans2
from gpflow import Parameter
from gpflow.inducing_variables.inducing_variables import InducingPointsBase
from gpflow import covariances as cov


num_classes=7
node_feats = np.random.randn(2708, 1433)
node_labels = np.sum(node_feats, axis=1)
node_labels=num_classes*(node_labels-np.min(node_labels))/(np.max(node_labels)-np.min(node_labels))
node_labels=(num_classes-1)*np.floor(node_labels)
idx_train, idx_val, idx_test =  np.array(range(140)),np.array(range(140,640)),np.array(range(1708,2708))
idx_train, idx_val, idx_test = tf.constant(idx_train), tf.constant(idx_val), tf.constant(idx_test)

X_train, y_train = node_feats[idx_train], node_labels[idx_train]
X_test, y_test = node_feats[idx_test], node_labels[idx_test]

def training_step(X_train, y_train, optimizer, gprocess):
    with tf.GradientTape(watch_accessed_variables=False) as tape:
        tape.watch(gprocess.trainable_variables)
        data=(X_train, y_train)
        objective = -gprocess.elbo(data)
        gradients = tape.gradient(objective, gprocess.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, gprocess.trainable_variables))
    return objective

def evaluate(X_val, y_val, gprocess):
    pred_y, pred_y_var = gprocess.predict_y(X_val)
    pred_classes = np.argmax(pred_y.numpy(), axis=-1)
    acc = np.mean(pred_classes == y_val)
    return acc

def sparse_mat_to_sparse_tensor(sparse_mat):
    """
    Converts a scipy csr_matrix to a tensorflow SparseTensor.
    """
    coo = sparse_mat.tocoo()
    indices = np.stack([coo.row, coo.col], axis=-1)
    tensor = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices, sparse_mat.data, sparse_mat.shape)
    return tensor

class GraphPolynomial(gpflow.kernels.base.Kernel):
    """
    GraphPolynomial kernel for node classification as introduced in
    Yin Chen Ng, Nicolo Colombo, Ricardo Silva: "Bayesian Semi-supervised
    Learning with Graph Gaussian Processes".
    """

    def __init__(self, sparse_adj_mat, feature_mat, degree=3.0, variance=1.0,
                 offset=1.0):
        super().__init__([1])
        self.degree = degree
        self.offset = Parameter(offset, transform=gpflow.utilities.positive())
        self.variance = Parameter(variance, transform=gpflow.utilities.positive())
        # Pre-compute the P-matrix for transforming the base covariance matrix
        # (c.f. paper for details).
        sparse_adj_mat[np.diag_indices(sparse_adj_mat.shape[0])] = 1.0
        self.sparse_P = sparse_mat_to_sparse_tensor(sparse_adj_mat)
        self.sparse_P = self.sparse_P / sparse_adj_mat.sum(axis=1)
        self.feature_mat = feature_mat

    def K(self, X, Y=None, presliced=False):
        X = tf.reshape(tf.cast(X, tf.int32), [-1])
        X2 = tf.reshape(tf.cast(Y, tf.int32), [-1]) if Y is not None else X

        base_cov = (self.variance * tf.matmul(self.feature_mat, self.feature_mat, transpose_b=True) + self.offset) ** self.degree
        cov = tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(self.sparse_P, base_cov)
        cov = tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(self.sparse_P, cov, adjoint_b=True)
        cov = tf.gather(tf.gather(cov, X, axis=0), X2, axis=1)
        # print(f"Kff: {cov.shape}")
        return cov

    def K_diag(self, X, presliced=False):
        return tf.linalg.diag_part(self.K(X))


class NodeInducingPoints(InducingPointsBase):
    """
    Set of real-valued inducing points. See parent-class for details.
    """
    pass



# Init inducing points
inducing_points = kmeans2(node_feats, len_train, minit='points')[0]    # use as many inducing points as training samples
#inducing_points = NodeInducingPoints(inducing_points)

# Init GP model
mean_function = Constant()
gprocess = SVGP(kernel, gpflow.likelihoods.MultiClass(num_classes),
                inducing_points, mean_function=mean_function,
                num_latent=num_classes, whiten=True, q_diag=False)
# Init optimizer
optimizer = tf.optimizers.Adam()

for epoch in range(200):
    elbo = -training_step(X_train, y_train, optimizer, gprocess)
    elbo = elbo.numpy()

    acc = evaluate(X_test, y_test, gprocess)
    print(f"{epoch}:\tELBO: {elbo:.5f}\tAcc: {acc:.3f}")
```

I am getting the following error message:

> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpf_env\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       268         try:
>   --> 269             func = self._cache[types]
>       270         except KeyError:
>
> KeyError: (, , )
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 for epoch in range(200):
>   ----> 2     elbo = -training_step(X_train, y_train, optimizer, gprocess)
>         3     elbo = elbo.numpy()
>         4 
>         5     acc = evaluate(idx_test, node_labels[idx_test], gprocess)
>
> in training_step(X_train, y_train,
>   optimizer, gprocess)
>        15         tape.watch(gprocess.trainable_variables)
>        16         data=(X_train, y_train)
>   ---> 17         objective = -gprocess.elbo(data)
>        18 
>        19         #objective = -gprocess.elbo(X_train, y_train)
>
> c:\users\asus\downloads\gpflow-develop\gpflow-develop\gpflow\models\svgp.py
>   in elbo(self, data)
>       152         This returns the evidence lower bound (ELBO) of the log marginal likelihood.
>       153         """
>   --> 154         return self.log_marginal_likelihood(data)
>       155 
>       156     def predict_f(self, Xnew: tf.Tensor, full_cov=False, full_output_cov=False) -> tf.Tensor:
>
> c:\users\asus\downloads\gpflow-develop\gpflow-develop\gpflow\models\model.py
>   in log_marginal_likelihood(self, *args, **kwargs)
>        43 
>        44     def log_marginal_likelihood(self, *args, **kwargs) -> tf.Tensor:
>   ---> 45         return self.log_likelihood(*args, **kwargs) + self.log_prior()
>        46 
>        47     def log_prior(self) -> tf.Tensor:
>
> c:\users\asus\downloads\gpflow-develop\gpflow-develop\gpflow\models\svgp.py
>   in log_likelihood(self, data)
>       138         X, Y = data
>       139         kl = self.prior_kl()
>   --> 140         f_mean, f_var = self.predict_f(X, full_cov=False, full_output_cov=False)
>       141         var_exp = self.likelihood.variational_expectations(f_mean, f_var, Y)
>       142         if self.num_data is not None:
>
> c:\users\asus\downloads\gpflow-develop\gpflow-develop\gpflow\models\svgp.py
>   in predict_f(self, Xnew, full_cov, full_output_cov)
>       164                               full_cov=full_cov,
>       165                               white=self.whiten,
>   --> 166                               full_output_cov=full_output_cov)
>       167         # tf.debugging.assert_positive(var)  # We really should make the tests pass with this here
>       168         return mu + self.mean_function(Xnew), var
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpf_env\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       276             self._cache[types] = func
>       277         try:
>   --> 278             return func(*args, **kwargs)
>       279 
>       280         except MDNotImplementedError:
>
> c:\users\asus\downloads\gpflow-develop\gpflow-develop\gpflow\conditionals\conditionals.py
>   in _conditional(Xnew, inducing_variable, kernel, function, full_cov,
>   full_output_cov, q_sqrt, white)
>        54     """
>        55     Kmm = Kuu(inducing_variable, kernel, jitter=default_jitter())  # [M, M]
>   ---> 56     Kmn = Kuf(inducing_variable, kernel, Xnew)  # [M, N]
>        57     Knn = kernel(Xnew, full=full_cov)
>        58     fmean, fvar = base_conditional(Kmn,
>
> ~\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpf_env\lib\site-packages\multipledispatch\dispatcher.py
>   in **call**(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       273                 raise NotImplementedError(
>       274                     'Could not find signature for %s: <%s>' %
>   --> 275                     (self.name, str_signature(types)))
>       276             self._cache[types] = func
>       277         try:
>
> NotImplementedError: Could not find signature for Kuf:

Comment: Could you please turn your code example into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), e.g. using toy data (such as `Xtrain = np.random.randn(140, 33)`) ? Otherwise, without being able to run your code as-is, it will be hard for others to figure out what exactly is going wrong for you.

Comment: Thank you, I edited it in a manner that should be runable (it still gives error)

Comment: Hi @enyhertbalo, I cannot reproduce your example - running your snippet results in ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so_7444.py", line 91, in <module>
    inducing_points = kmeans2(node_feats, len_train, minit='points')[0]    # use as many inducing points as training samples
NameError: name 'len_train' is not defined```. Please try and make your example as small as possible while still reproducing the same issue.